# ExternalInterface.addCallback with 2 arguments

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash

I am trying to pass 2 variables from javascript to flash. I figured I could do something like this i as3 to try and recieve them.

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("callAs", muscle, tension);
```

Sadly this throws an error

1137: Incorrect number of arguments.  Expected no more than 2.

Is there a way to send 2 variables instead of having to make 2 calls each time?

Thanks in advance!
Resin

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible.

```
ExternalInterface.addCallback("theFunctionNameInJavascript", theFunctionNameInActionscript);

function theFunctionNameInActionscript(param1:String, param2:String):void {
//do something with param1;
//do something with param2;

}
```

Then in Javascript you would have something like...

```
<!-- work out if we are on Mac or PC -->
function getFlashMovie(movieName) {
    var isIE = navigator.appName.indexOf("Microsoft") != -1;
    return (isIE) ? window[movieName] : document[movieName];
}

function theFunctionNameInJavascript(swf, param1, param2) {
    getFlashMovie(swf).theFunctionNameInActionscript(param1, param2);
}
```

And you would trigger this with something like...

```
<form action="javascript:theFunctionNameInJavascript('idNameOfYourSWF', 'thisisparam1', 'thisIsParam2')" id="form">
<input type="submit" value="Click Me" />
</form>
```

Comment: I changed the script a bit, but I think it would work. Certainly gave me the understanding to get mine working ;) Thanks!